# ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable NativeApplication is not defined

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe

> ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable NativeApplication is not
>   defined.

showing while I have import of relavnet package: `import flash.desktop`

```
 import ISC.*;
    import flash.desktop.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.*;

    public class Back_lst extends Object
    {
        public function Back_lst()
        {
            Game.gameLink.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, this.exit2_fnc);
            Game.gameLink.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, this.return_fnc);
            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this.exit_fnc);
            return;
        }// end function
```

Comment: yes, its not imported successfully. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Are you creating Air project? Check settings, you might publishing just swf file.